# Imshow Plotly colour toggling using legend

Tags: python, plotly, legend

I'm currently working on a data visualisation using Plotly in Python, and I've hit a bit of a roadblock.

I have a 2D array representing image data, and I'm using plotly.express.imshow to display it. The image displays just fine, and now I'm trying to add an interactive element to it.
What I want to achieve is to have a legend where each label corresponds to a unique colour in the image, and by clicking on a label in the legend, I can toggle the visibility of all the pixels of that specific colour in the image.

I've tried adding empty scatter plots with the right colours to the legend, but I can't seem to connect these to the actual pixels in the image. Clicking the legend items doesn't affect the visibility of the pixels.

Does anyone have experience with this or any suggestions on achieving this interactive colour toggling in an imshow plot in Plotly? I'm open to any ideas or workarounds that could make this work.

Comment: You could create one image (or heatmap) trace per color you want to show in the legend, ie. filter the 2D array by the given color and create an image/heatmap from that, repeat for every colors you need, then merge all image traces into the same figure. If you need more details, please provide a mwe.